# Contact form 7 not using Ajax if i am logged in to my WP Dashboard

Tags: ajax, rest, contact-form-7

If i am not logged in contact form 7 JS files not getting loaded blocked and Ajax is not working.
My website is for normal end user i can’t force them to login so please give me solution to this

**in brief:**

I have edited
1. Htaccess
2. Disabled all plugins
3. Disabled Rest Api
4. Plugin Load Filter (which i don’t know how will solve my problem)

i have tried many things but my contact form Ajax not working if i am not logged in.
i can see if i don’t log in Contact form 7 JS and CSS Files getting blocked with this error “net::ERR_ABORTED 409”

with this everytime i hit submit button page loded with form id and get submitted but i need it to work with ajax.

If i am logged in Ajax is working. if i am not logged in it form needed to refresh the page

**Screenshot:**

Before Submit Hit – prntscr.com/rpyd61
After Submit Hit – prntscr.com/rpyd0j

Please help i am struggling with this error i have seen all forums on internet.

Thanks in advance!
Sahil

Answer (score -1):

The issue was with Internet Connection silly!

i have tried another internet connection everything works fine!

this issue troubled for many days and the problem was internet connection there are many threads on this contact form issue i hope this comment saves your time!

Thanks!